# ReactJS can not access response object inside setState

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to update the setSet as part of output from my RestAPI. However I am getting an error that response object is undefined. I am able to log it outside `setState` method.

**Code**

```
addNewTodo = () => {
axios.post('http://localhost:5001/todos', "task="+this.state.newTodoList.task)
      .then(response=>console.log(response.data))
      .then(response=>{
              this.setState(prevState=>({
                  TodoList: prevState.TodoList.push(response.data),
              }))
            });
{this.toggleNewTodoModal()}
}
```

I get following log in console before error

> {task: "ddd", id: "todo10"}

**Error:**

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of undefined

at following line

> TodoList: prevState.TodoList.push(response.data),

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So your first `.then` returns a console log, meaning your second `.then` will no longer have any values. If you change your code to this:

Regarding pushing new Data to react state array, The recommended approach in later React versions is to use an updater function when modifying states to prevent race conditions. So pushing new Data to state array should be something like below

```
axios
    .post('http://localhost:5001/todos', 'task=' + this.state.newTodoList.task)
    .then(response => {
        console.log(response.data);
        this.setState(prevState => ({
            TodoList: [...prevState.TodoList, response.data],
        }));
    });
```

It should work just fine. You can chain `.then` as much as you like, as long as you return some values, and not a console log, for example, in the `fetch`:

```
fetch('some_url', {
  method: 'GET',
})
.then(res => res.json()) // this returns the data 
.then(data => console.log(data)) // this has access to the data
```

Comment: TodoList is a map and not a list, and that's why I was trying to `prevState.TodoList.push(response.data)`.  I tried `[...prevState.TodoList, response.data]` to and it gives error too.

Answer (score 1):

My state object was a map, and so following worked for me. 
**State**

```
  state = {
    TodoList: {},
    }
```

**Updating State**

```
axios
.post('http://localhost:5001/todos', 'task=' + this.state.newTodoList.task)
.then(response => {
  const {id, task} = response.data
    this.setState(prevState => ({
        TodoList: {...prevState.TodoList,
            [id]: task},
    }));
});
```